# My Amazon Quicksight dashboard does not load. The dashboard is using a SPICE dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I have dashboards in AWS QuickSight that use Spice datasets. Occasionally the dashboards do not load data (they seem to refresh forever and never load the data).

Refreshing/closing the browser doesn't seem to help. Eventually the dashboard will load at some point later (don't have a precise time but it will be much longer than a few minutes).

It doesn't happen for all users, at the same time. For example it may happen to me but it works for someone else at the same time (same dashboard).

Normally the Spice dashboards I have are pretty fast.

Thank you!

Comment: Also had this problem, still finding a solution though.

Comment: @JayHyber Same problem here. Any luck finding a root cause?

Comment: I still see it occasionally but we have very few users so it isn't a priority for us. Also we might be moving away from QuickSight soon. I'd recommend asking AWS support, they are usually pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing problem in AWS quick sight with Direct query mode, if you use query mode as SPICE this issue gets resolved for more info you can post here as well

https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/dataset-direct-query-timeout/2703